# How to force python based Heroku to install Java

Tags: python, heroku

I'm deploying a web server by Heroku based on Python2.

In order to use JPype1 module, I need to install java in my server.

But I'm not sure how this work.
Thank you :)

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/customizing-the-jdk#prerequisites  or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44749732/running-a-java-subprocess-from-a-python-app-in-heroku?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa