# Running a java subprocess from a python app in Heroku

Tags: java, python, heroku, paas

I am new to Heroku. The backend logic of my flask web app is actually running a Java subprocess (`subprocess.call( ...)` ) to get some helper data. (I know it's a bad thing to do)
On deployment, Heroku works as expected and installs Python runtime and frameworks from requirements.txt but not JDK.

Any way I can configure Java in the same and make this work ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
$ heroku buildpacks:add heroku/jvm
```

Then redeploy with a `git push heroku master`. This will install the JDK into your slug.

Comment: tried this. But on launching heroku run bash, i am still getting -  java : 'command not found'.

Comment: Try `git commit -m "redeploy" --allow-empty` and then `git push heroku master`

Comment: This actually solved the problem. Sorry for accepting late!